# Mac OS X Terminal - Display list of File Types from Subfolders

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I have an external hard drive that has the content of a Recovered Drive.  All the folders have 'recup_dir.XX' names and there are over a thousand.

I have copied over all content I can think of, of specific file types using:

```
find . -type f -name \*.jpg -exec cp \{\} /Volumes/somedrive/somefolder/ \;
```

I went through all file types I can think of - but I want to see what file types are on the drive and in the sub folders.

What command can I use that will go through all folders and sub folders and display 'total's for each file type?

```
du -hcs
```

Gives a total of the Drive- but I am after a Total per File Type.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction.  I have thousands of folders and I want to make sure I haven't forgotten any file types - so want to get a list of them.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with awk (as well as other scripting languages).  Here is a script in `awk`:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -ls | awk '
{
    type = $11;
    if ( type ~ /\./ ) {
        sub(/^.*\./, "", type);
    } else {
        type = ".";
    }
    sizes[type] += $7;
}
END {
    for ( type in sizes ) {
        printf "%10d %s\n", sizes[type], type;
    }
}' | sort -r -n
```

It uses an array `sizes` with the file-suffix as an index.  `awk` does not have built-in sorting, but you can do that by piping the result through `sort`.

For example, here is output from MacOS running in a copy of the Debian scripts for the xterm package:

```
341580 html
 72830 /changelog
  8458 /copyright
  5846 /control
  5754 diff
  2401 /rules
  1817 Debian
  1328 asc
  1284 postinst
   964 1
   723 prerm
   631 /NEWS
   442 faq
   419 /local/lxterm
   279 ctlseqs
   162 conf
   127 install
   125 /tests/control
   102 /watch
   101 docs
    58 /patches/series
    23 /clean
    12 /source/format
     3 /compat
```

What you see when running the script depends on what file-suffixes exist.  In this example, there are a couple of large ".html" files.

Comment: I ran this on OSX and grepped for mp4 or mpeg but didn't get any results